# Multiple Column Index vs Multiple Indexes/Index Merge

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

Let's assume we have a table with 4 columns: A, B, C, and D

Let's assume we have a few queries that will join or perform a clause against these columns:

```
Q1: Where A = ?
Q2: Where A = ?, B = ?
Q3: Where A = ?, B = ?, C = ?
```

Since we know we will use these columns in three different contexts, is it best to create three different indexes? Or three different multiple indexes?

Index Merge:

```
Idx1: Create index A_idx ON table (A)
Idx2: Create index B_idx ON table (B)
Idx3: Create index C_idx ON table (C)
```

Multiple Index

```
Idx1: Create index A_idx ON table(A)
Idx2: Create index AB_idx ON table(A,B)
Idx3: Create index ABC_idx ON table(A,B,C)
```

This is a simplified case. Let's assume we have 10-15 columns, that will be joined or where'd in different ways and combinations. Is it best to create multiple column indexes for these combinations they will receive? Or just find the smallest set of multiple columns that are most frequently used, build a multiple column index on those, and then create individual indexes for the rest?

Answer (score 3):

Composite index on (A,B,C) will cover the 3 queries, so you don't need index on (A) and ON (A,B). It's also faster than index_merge.

The only reason to have more than one index is if some queries won't be covered by the index (they include B and C, but not A for example)

Also keep in mind that one of the most important characteristics of the column, to decide if it should be included in the index, is not if it's used in a query, but it's cardinality. If the query on this column won't exclude a lot of the rows, you should not include it in the index.

Let's say you have A,B,C
For a given value of A you have 20% of the rows. From those rows, for a given value of B you have 1% of the rows. Lets say those conditions (A,B) filter 1000 rows from the table. After applying C, you receive 850 rows. Index on C is not effective and (A,B) is the best index for this query

Comment: I don't get your last point. Reading 850 rows is (slightly but still) better than reading 1000 rows.

Comment: when you have to read more then 50% of the results, table scan is better then index scan, since for every row in the index you have to read row in the table as well. Except for covering indexes, if C will make your index covering one (it will contain all the columns retrieved by the query), use it

Comment: If you mean that index `(A,B)` is better than index `(C)` in this situation, I agree. But `(A,B,C)` would be even better.

Comment: So it's not a problem to create a multiple column index (A,B,C) even if many of my queries will just reference, say A, but some others may reference B,C? I see what you're saying about omitting indexes on columns that have high cardinality.

But back to the main point - if I create an index A,B,C  -- it's sufficient to use that in cases where I only want A, or only want B, or only want C? And still cover cases for A&B, B&C, C&A.

What if this grows to say, 10 columns that will be often used in clauses, but rarely compositely.

Comment: (A,B,C) may be used for queries that reference A, A and B or A, B and C. It can't be used for queries that reference B and C, but not A
if you want only B or only C, you need separate indexes

Comment: @Darhazer So - the order of the columns defined in the index is very important I see.. (A,B,C) seems as if it firsts checks A, then B? If A isn't requested, the key is ignored? Does this mean a query referencing A,C will be skipped on a index of (A,B,C)? Or as long as the first column in the index is matched, we are good? Thanks for the discussion :)

Comment: Yes, the order is very important, since the index is a binary tree. On a query (A,C) the index will be used, but only to find rows matching A, then `using where` will be used to filter the results.